# Java Class with constructor asking for user input

Tags: java, arrays

Working on homework for Java class, question I am having difficulty on is

> Average — the constructor. It will allocate memory for the array. Use a for loop to repeatedly display a prompt for the user which should indicate that user
>   Copyright © 2016 Pearson Education, Inc., Hoboken NJ
>   should enter score number 1, score number 2, etc. Note: The computer starts
>   counting with 0, but people start counting with 1, and your prompt should account
>   for this. For example, when the user enters score number 1, it will be stored in
>   indexed variable 0. The constructor will then call the selectionSort and the
>   calculateMean methods.

So that being said what I have done is created an AverageDriver class as instructed which creates a new instance of the Average class. When I run the main method no errors occur but the constructor does not ask for any user input, it just skips past the constructor and displays an array of 5 zeros.

AverageDriver code:

```
public class AverageDriver
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Average calcAverage = new Average();

      System.out.print(calcAverage.toString());
   }

}
```

***and Average code here:***

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
import java.util.Arrays; 

public class Average

{

final int GRADES = 5;

private int[] data = new int[GRADES] ; 

private double mean = 0; 
  public void Average()    {
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);       


  for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
  {
     System.out.print("Enter grade number "
                       + (i+1) + ": ");
     data[i] = keyboard.nextInt();
  }

  selectionSort();
  calculateMean();    } 


  public void selectionSort()
  {
     Arrays.sort(data);
  }


  public void calculateMean()
  {
     for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
        mean += data[i];

     mean = mean/5;                                  
  }


  public String toString()
  {
     String stringData = Arrays.toString(data);
     String stringMean = Double.toString(mean);

     return stringData;
  }
   }
```

Comment: Dear mankind, are we seriously trying to help this student to *prompt for user input in a constructor*?

Comment: If reading user input in the constructor is really what the exercise wants then I would consider switching to a different course. This will not help you learn Java